# Select statement with string expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table but i don't know its columns. It name is X

I can find its columns with the following code:

```
DECLARE @columnNames NVARCHAR(4000) = ''
SELECT @columnNames = @columnNames + ', ' + COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'X'
```

Now, i want to use select statement in my table, but how?

I think, it should be like that. I didn't find correct way:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@columnNames, 2, LEN(@columnNames)) FROM X
```

edit:

Actually i want to merge columns without id column.

```
DECLARE @columnNames NVARCHAR(4000) = ''
SELECT @columnNames = @columnNames + ' + ' + COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'X' AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'id'
```

And then

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@columnNames, 4, LEN(@columnNames)) FROM X
```

Comment: I know it's bad form, but why doesn't `select * from X` work for you?

Comment: actually i want to merge columns without id column.

SELECT @columnNames = @columnNames + ' + ' + COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'X' AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'id'

and then i want to use select...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select the fields in the string you fetch you would need to use `EXEC` (or `sp_executesql`)

```
DECLARE @columnNames NVARCHAR(4000) = ''
SELECT @columnNames = @columnNames + case when len(@columnNames)=0 then '' else ', ' end + COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = X

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1024) = 'select ' + @columnNames + ' from X'
EXEC (@SQL)
```

Answer (score 2):

Following the clarified goal and explanation as to why `*` won't work for you, you would need to concatenate the entire `SELECT` statement and use dynamic SQL. You should use `QUOTE_NAME` to avoid problems with non standard names.

See [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL: Dealing with Dynamic Table and Column Names](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#objectnames)

Answer (score 2):

If you are selecting **all** of the columns of your table, why don't just use `SELECT * FROM X`?. The other way is with dynamic sql and thats not a good idea.

Comment: because of merge columns... thanx for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use dynamic SQL to do that, but be aware of the dangers, read this http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

But since you are selecting all columns I don't see the point in what you are doing...just use `SELECT * FROM X`